# Does Google Analytics enhanced e-commerce tracking replace "ecommerce:addTransaction"?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

We currently use Google's analytics.js library for tracking and it's working today:

```
ga( 'ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': $scope.Data.Cart.ConfirmationNumber,      // Transaction ID. Required.
    'affiliation': 'lexicontech.com',               // Affiliation or store name.
    'revenue': $scope.Data.Cart.OrderTotal,         // Grand Total.
    'shipping': $scope.Data.Cart.ShippingTotal,     // Shipping.
    'tax': $scope.Data.Cart.TaxTotal                // Tax.
})

ga( 'ecommerce:send' );
```

.. We would like to start using [Google's Enhanced E-commerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-actvities) feature.  Should we remove the above `ga( 'ecommerce:addTransaction' ...` code completely and replace it with the following code? .. Or should we keep what we have and simply add the new `ec:` function calls?:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency).
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your way of thinking is good.

Classic ecommerce is only about tracking transaction. Enhanced Ecommerce contains this and it is called purchase. You need to update your current code in the way you showed.

### Example in ehnanced ecommerce

```
// products (example from google developers)
ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).
  'coupon': 'APPARELSALE',          // Product coupon (string).
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
});

// transaction details
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency).
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});

// event or pageview
ga('send','pageview');
```

The event or pageview is important, because in Enahnced Ecommerce does not exist transaction type event. So you send ecommerce data with regulat pageview or any event. Usually non-interaction event.

Checkout documentation - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

### Further enahncements

Enhanced ecommerce contains all events in shopping behavior before purhcase, so you can have deep insight about users flow in your ecommerce site,

Answer (score 1):

The new enhanced ecommerce plugin *is* intended to replace the regular ecommerce one.

I believe sending regular ecommerce hits may not even be supported in the mobile SDKs and will likely be deprecated in analytics.js soon.